# The type or namespace name 'Graphics' does not exist in the namespace 'Project.Android'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms application, In which I have added a custom renderer to set the background of native edit text. Following Code shows error. 
`var shape = new ShapeDrawable(new Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes.RectShape());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that your application uses the namespace `Project.Android` and the type system will think `Android.Grapics.Drawables.Shapes.RectShape` belongs in `Project.Android`.

You some options:

1. Change your namespace for the project and in all your classes
2. Prefix `Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes.RectShape` with `global::` like: `global::Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes.RectShape`
3. Add a using at the top of the file telling where `RectShape` comes from: `using RectShape = Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes.RectShape` and just use `new RectShape()`